# Where does elastic beanstalk mount docker volume by default?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Elastic Beanstalk environment running with single docker container in it. When I ssh into the host machine and use `df -h` I tells me that machine has 10GB of storage. But if I connect to docker container and `df` in there it shows that `dev/mapper/docker-202:` has 99GB.

There are no volumes mounted explicitly so I'm wondering where does this number come from.

Comment: When you say *I ssh into the machine and use df -h* you mean host or container? Are you saying that you have 10Gb storage in host and 99Gb in docker?

Comment: I've updated the question. Pretty much yeah. Docker tells me that container has a volume with 99GB.

Comment: Have you checked your volumes doing `docker inspect <container_name>`?

Comment: Checking that tells that volumes are `null`. As I've mentioned it's not really mounted anywhere. If that helps it's uses `devicemapper`.